# Magento 2 : URL Rewrite management

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, router

In magento 2, I want to do like this below way :

**`http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1`** => This is **category url** (***Products*** is *main category* and **category1** is *sub-category* of *products*)

Now, there are 2 tabs available in category1 category

- video
- photos

### Expected Result :

Now, If I execute this below url then, it should not be return 404

```
http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1/?tab=video

http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1/?tab=photos

http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1/video

http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1/photos
```

- If 1st url execute then, video tab should be active & if 2nd url
  execute then, photos tab should be active.

### Actual Result :

Right now, it's return 404. I think it's consider as action name and action will be not found so.

What should i need to do ? Is there any way to override url rewrite file or plugin ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is http://php722.local.com/m231 your base url?

Comment: Yes. It's base url.

Comment: Are you able to hit the url http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1 successfully?

Comment: Yes. It's working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The query part of the URL needs to be before the `#`. Browsers only send the part before the `#` to the server. The part after `#` is for auto-scrolling to elements using the element `id` attribute.

Try to hit the URL `http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1#video` or `http://php722.local.com/m231/products/category1#photos`

where photos and videos are id of the element.

Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#cite_ref-14

Comment: I can't able to use #. Because, That url is already live and also in seo.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do using ?tab= .... In M1, it's working from app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php loadByRequestPath() function. How to do in M2?

Comment: Not sure, may be you need to write custom module to process this type of URLs which contains video and photo query params.

Comment: Do you know about core url rewrite M2 function which is useful to make working as like product page ?

Comment: Not sure, need to check.